# Native Query is not working in JPA: why?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I want to make a query that returns a list of objects from a database. There seem to be something wrong with the query because of the error : Encountered 'by' at line x column xx. I don't know what is wrong about the query. Can someone pls help.

```
public List<Film> getFilmsVanRegisseur(String voornaam, String achternaam){

        List<Film> l;
        //de fout zit in de query
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(""
                + "select films.filmnaam,films.uitgavejaar "
                + "from films "
                + "inner join regisseurs on films.regisseur = regisseurs.id "
                + "inner join filmmedewerkers on filmmedewerkers.id = regisseurs.id "
                + "where filmmedewerkers.voornaam = ? and filmmedewerkers.achternaam = ?"
                + "group by films.filmnaam, films.uitgavejaar", Film.class);
        q.setParameter(1, voornaam);
        q.setParameter(2, achternaam);

        l = q.getResultList();

        return l;

    }
```

The tables in the database are Films, Filmmedewerkers and Regisseur which is a specific type of Filmmedewerkers. I want to make a query that returns a list of Films from a Regisseur with a voornaam and achternaam (as you can see in the parameters) the tables are correctly connected.

Comment: You forgot to add a space at the end of `ilmmedewerkers.achternaam = ?"` so the group will be concatenated directly behind it: `ilmmedewerkers.achternaam = SOMETHINGgroup by`. So the `group` isn't detected and sql doesn't know what your `by` keyword is supposed to do without it.

Comment: Hint, especially since this is a native query: print it somewhere or grab it via a debugger and execute it in a database client. That way you'll see whether the query works in general or what problems the database would return - without JPA or even Java being involved. In your case you'd probably have seen the missing space quite fast.

Comment: Since you are selecting only your grouping columns (and all of those), you could consider using `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of grouping at all.  That would be shorter and clearer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger but in some cases slower...

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I'd find it surprising if the `SELECT DISTINCT` were slower in a case such as this -- in fact, if there were a measurable speed difference then my first guess would be that it is *faster*.  After all, the DB has the option of implementing the `SELECT DISTINCT` exactly as the OP's `GROUP BY` alternative.  Of course, performance is notoriously difficult to predict, and query performance even more so than many other kinds.

Comment: It depends on many factors but a most by the used database.